# Vue's event @click not working in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

my Vue's event @click not working in dropdown menu:

```
<template>
  <div class="masthead__content">
    <div class="category-list">
      <div class="category-list__container">
        <ul class="category-list__slide">
          <li v-for="(item,index) in mutableList" :key="index" @click="updateboxes(item.id)" :id="'category-'+item.slug" :class="{ 'category-list__slide--hidden': !item.visible }" :style="'order: '+(index+1)+';'">
            <a role="button" class="btn active btn--ghost-secondary " v-bind:class="{ 'btn--active': item.id==activo,  }">
              {{ item.name }}
            </a>
          </li>
          <li id="category-list--dropdown" :style="'order: '+position+';'">
            <div class="dropdown dropdown--filled" v-bind:class="{ 'dropdown--active': position>=activo,  }">
              <select id="select_dropdown" name="dropdown" aria-describedby="help_text_dropdown" class="dropdown__select">
                <option value="">Más</option>
              </select>
            <div id="div_dropdown" name="dropdown" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="label_dropdown" aria-describedby="help_text_dropdown" class="dropdown__selection">
              <label id="label_dropdown" for="select_dropdown" class="dropdown__placeholder">
                Más
              </label>
          </div>
          <div aria-labelledby="label_dropdown" role="menu" class="dropdown__menu">
            <div v-for="(item,index) in moreOptions" v-bind:key="index" :value="item.val" class="dropdown__option" @click.prevent="updateboxes(item.id)">
              {{ item.val }}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown__arrow">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="caret-down" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-caret-down fa-w-10">
              <path fill="currentColor" d="M31.3 192h257.3c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L174.1 354.8c-7.8 7.8-20.5 7.8-28.3 0L17.2 226.1C4.6 213.5 13.5 192 31.3 192z" class=""></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <!---->
          <!---->
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
.......
updateboxes(i) {            
  this.activo = i
  this.$eventHub.$emit('update', i);
        },
</script>
```

It happens because the dropdownmenu class is with display: none, if I remove it if the click works ... I don't understand why it doesn't work, if when you click the dropdownmenu opens ...

Comment: if it has `display:none` it would be hidden

Comment: Yes, but if class = "dropdown__selection" is clicked, the dropdown__menu should be displayed, but the @click does not work.

Comment: You do not show the whole component code. Maybe some parent object is intercepting the click. There is nothing to see in your code that explains why it would not be clickable.

Comment: Hello, I updated the code, thank you.
Demo live: https://tarjetaactiva.es/